# Visual Studio/Chrome not updating HTML/Typescript

Tags: html, typescript, visual-studio

I am running my company's application locally and making some HTML/TS changes. However, whenever I save/hot reload and reload the browser, nothing changes.

I can stop debugging, build/rebuild, and run and the changes remain the same.

On a hunch I deleted the entire file from the directory and ran the application and nothing changed.

What am I missing here?

Web.Config is all configured to our dev environment currently, main web application is configured locally.

Comment: What server are you using?
Does restarting the server cause changes to be made?

Comment: changing servers does not fix the issue.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and see. If that's empty, and your files are gone, your server might be pointing at the wrong location, or your server has a cache. Hard to know with no details about the server.

Comment: Browser cache was it. If I disabled browser caching in chrome devtools, I had no problems. Thanks for setting me on the right track!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with Chrome. Inside Dev Tools -> Settings -> Network -> Disable cache (while DevTools is open).

When I clicked this option, it stopped caching old changes, and I was able to see my updates again with each hot reload.

Comment: Are you using Angular or React?
Ideally your browser should detect bundle changes, and retrieve the latest code.

Comment: Angular. And I agree, I am unsure why it wasn't